# differentiate ln(f(x))

Tags: calculus

$\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$
I am given the answer $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$
But I can't seem to simplify it till that after many tries.
my solution was: $\frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$
can anyone confirm?

Comment: Can you simplify your expression? Alternatively, note than your function is $\operatorname{arsinh} x$.

Comment: "my solution was: $(1+x/\sqrt(x+1))/(x+\sqrt(x^2+1))$" You probably mean $(1+x/\sqrt{x^2+1})/(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$, which is also $((\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)/\sqrt{x^2+1})/(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$, that is, $1/\sqrt{x^2+1}$

Comment: thank you, did not spot it

Answer (score 0):

your solution is correct:
$$d\left[ ln\left( x+\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+1 }  \right)  \right] =\frac { 1 }{ x+\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+1 }  } d\left[ x+\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+1 }  \right] =\frac { 1 }{ x+\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+1 }  } \left[ 1+\frac { x }{ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+1 }  }  \right] =\\ =\frac { \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+1 } +x }{ x+\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+1 }  } \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+1 }  } =\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+1 }  } $$